# How to condense code : know the limits of an image after rotation

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, trigonometry

Im a beginner in Java.

I have an image which I know the number of rows and the number of columns. I would like to calculate the limits of the new image after a rotation. 
This is my code :

```
       BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read( new File( "D:\\Users...jpg" ) );
        xmaxOrigine = myImage.getWidth() - 1;
        ymaxOrigine = myImage.getHeight() - 1;
        angle = 12;

        angleRadian = Math.toRadians( angle );
        cos = Math.cos( angleRadian );
        sin = Math.sin( angleRadian );

        p1X = (int) ( ( xmaxOrigine * cos ) - ( ymaxOrigine * sin ) );
        p1Y = (int) ( ( xmaxOrigine * sin ) + ( ymaxOrigine * cos ) );

        xmin_f = xmin_f < p1X ? xmin_f : p1X;
        xmax_f = xmax_f < p1X ? p1X : xmax_f;
        ymin_f = ymin_f < p1Y ? ymin_f : p1Y;
        ymax_f = ymax_f < p1Y ? p1Y : ymax_f;

        p2X = (int) ( ( 0  * cos ) - ( ymaxOrigine * sin ) );
        p2Y = (int) ( ( 0 * sin ) + ( ymaxOrigine * cos ) );

        xmin_f = xmin_f < p2X ? xmin_f : p2X;
        xmax_f = xmax_f < p2X ? p2X : xmax_f;
        ymin_f = ymin_f < p2Y ? ymin_f : p2Y;
        ymax_f = ymax_f < p2Y ? p2Y : ymax_f;

        p3X = (int) ( ( xmaxOrigine * cos ) - ( 0 * sin ) );
        p3Y = (int) ( ( xmaxOrigine * sin ) + ( 0 * cos ) );

        xmin_f = xmin_f < p3X ? xmin_f : p3X;
        xmax_f = xmax_f < p3X ? p3X : xmax_f;
        ymin_f = ymin_f < p3Y ? ymin_f : p3Y;
        ymax_f = ymax_f < p3Y ? p3Y : ymax_f;

        p4X = 0;
        p4Y = 0;

        xmin_f = xmin_f < p4X ? xmin_f : p4X;
        xmax_f = xmax_f < p4X ? p4X : xmax_f;
        ymin_f = ymin_f < p4Y ? ymin_f : p4Y;
        ymax_f = ymax_f < p4Y ? p4Y : ymax_f;

        widthFinal = xmax_f - xmin_f;
        heightFinal = ymax_f - ymin_f;
```

As you can see I look for the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax for each points. I would like to make this operation once if it is possible.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you having a problem with the code not working? If you want a review of your code or suggestions for improvements, you should post this in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: Your code gets a plus as it is for being nice and tidy. It is easy to simplify code when it is already organized like this. One example: there's `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` which you should use instead of the ternary operator. Most of the code seems to amount to finding a max or min of a set of integers, so write a function `maxOfAll(int... is)` and call it. In Java 8 an `IntStream` will do that for you.

Comment: Its seem to be a good idea, but my project is in Java 1.7... And I'm a complete beginner in java, do you have an idea of a function more developed? @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: No problem, implement `maxOfAll()` yourself in terms of `Math.max()`. Just a bit of thinking is all it takes.

Comment: Ok in fact Math.max() seems to be what I need, but It's a shame that it can take only two variable. I will try to make a function which can take like 10 variable but it seems complicated to me @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: You should make a function which takes a _variable_ number of arguments: `maxOfAll(int... ints)` and implement it with two (maybe three) lines of code.

Comment: I try to answer, Do you agree , is that code works well for you? @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make something like that :

```
public int maxOfAll(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    //Look for the maximum of 4 variable
    int temp1max = Math.max( a, b );
    int temp2max = Math.max( temp1max, c );
    int temp3 = Math.max( temp2max, d );
    return temp3;
}

public int minOfAll (int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    //Look for the minimum of 4 variable
    int temp1 = Math.min( a, b );
    int temp2 = Math.min( temp1, c );
    int temp3 = Math.min( temp2, d );
    return temp3;
}
```

Do you agree ?

Comment: Note that it is not appropriate to use answers for discussion. But, to respond: you have implemented the functions for a fixed number of arguments and basically you have "unrolled" the loop which would normally be used. You should try to find the solution which can work with an `int[]` of size which is not known in advance. A signature `maxOfAll(int... ints)` would give you this array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code and question correctly you want to find the bounds of the image after rotation. If this is not an assignment, where you should implement this yourself, you should probably just use the [`AffineTransformOp.getBounds2D(BufferedImage)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#getBounds2D(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)) method, which is made for exactly this purpose:

```
// Read the image and set angle (as before)
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(...));
double angle = 12;

// Create AffineTransformOp to do the calculation
AffineTransform rotation = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle);
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(rotation, null);

Rectangle bounds = op.getBounds2D(myImage).getBounds(); // Correctly rounded bounds

// You can now use bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width and bounds.height as you like.
// Example:

widthFinal = bounds.width;
heightFinal = bounds.height;
```